# R package was installed by version with different internals

Tags: r, rpostgresql

On my Win 7 Ent x64 I installed RStudio R-3.4.2.

I installed few packages that I need (`RPostgreSQL`, `sqldf`, etc..)
But when I'm executing code, these libraries give me errors:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
```

> Error: package ‘RPostgreSQL’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘RPostgreSQL’ was built under R version 3.5.0

All of the packages are downloaded from CRAN. `RPostgrSQL` is 0.6-2 version.

I'm pretty sure that solution is quite simple, but I searched a lot and still cannot find the solution.

Comment: did u try reinstalling with new R session?

Answer (score 3):

How did you install the package `RPostgreSQL`? If you used 
`install.packages("RPostgreSQL")` on your Windows it installed using binaries, which may have been built using a different R version. In your case, 3.5.0 vs 3.4.2.

Try using `install.packages("RPostgreSQL", type="source")`. This way your machine will compile the package from source using your version of R, and it should work.

If the package needs C/C++/Fortran compilation, you will als need RTools installed on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find all packages installed with the old version R like this:

```sh
grep 'Built: R 3.4' /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/*/DESCRIPTION > temp
```

and then you can uninstall the packages with `remove.packages()`