# Error: package was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install packages 'cluster' in R.

```
R Details:

platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu     
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.3                         
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree
```

I am getting following error:

```
Loading required package: cluster
Error: package \u2018cluster\u2019 was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/modules//R_X11.so':
  /usr/lib64/R/modules//R_X11.so: undefined symbol: ALTSTRING_ELT
2: package \u2018cluster\u2019 was built under R version 3.5.0
```

I tried to remove the package and re installed it.

1. remove.packages("cluster")
2. install.packages("cluster")

I also tried with following:

install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/cluster/cluster_2.0.4.tar.gz")
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/cluster/cluster_2.0.0.tar.gz")

install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/cluster_2.0.7-1.tar.gz")
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/cluster/cluster_2.0.2.tar.gz")

but nothing is working. Same error is coming.

Please help. I am new to R stuff.

Thanks

Comment: I expect there is a savvier way to do this, but when I had this error message, the `remove.packages()` command didn't work for me either (I suspect it could be because my R_LIBS_USER may not have been pointing to the correct directory). From outside R, I had to go to the directory where the package was installed, delete the package there and reinstall it in R, which worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R package was installed by version with different internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890505/r-package-was-installed-by-version-with-different-internals)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144957 - where I've suggested an answer